# How to restrict sqlite only to execute SELECT statements, and not INSERT, UPDATE

Tags: c#, sqlite, select

I have a reports page where you can enter the query manually for a report. How can I block any INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statements, and only run SELECT?

```
using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
            {
                var da = new SQLiteDataAdapter
                {
                    SelectCommand = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection)
                };
                try
                {
                    da.Fill(table);
                }
```

I could check if the query string contains "INSERT", "UPDATE" or "DELETE", but I don't think it's a good practice.

Comment: Is there a reason this couldn't be handled by using a connection that only has Read privileges?

Comment: @Sorax - I didn't think sqlite had users and permissions.  how do you create a read only session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an `EXPLAIN` statement to break the query down into VM instructions and examine the `opcode` column of the output.  If the value `"OpenWrite"` occurs then the query is not read-only.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I picked this one, as there can by any other malicious commands like DROP.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the query string is not good practice? Compared to what? Allowing a user to enter any SQL statement they want to in your report page? I can't think of a much worse practice than that. If you're going to allow that sort of thing, you absolutely need to somehow restrict the types of statements they enter, and maybe require a Where clause (to avoid millions of rows being returned) etc.

Comment: good practice would be to create a user in the database that only has read permissions.  however, I don't think sqlite supports users/permissions, which is why the user is asking the question.  The bad practice the OP is talking about is trying to guess every possible malicious thing a user could enter - when you try to do this, you are begging for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

in fact did you check what happens when you try to fill the table with the data adapter having anything else than a select in the query variable? I doubt you get an empty table or dataset, I would expect an exception in which case you could rollback the transaction.

I would anyway try to create the connection as readonly as suggested above by Sorax and I would actually parse the query variable as well.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with a INSERT statement, and it inserted a row in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Since the SQlite database is just one file, my guess is that you can make the database readonly through the filesystem. This is of course not a fancy solution but is one that does not require any code (of course except when you're throwing exceptions when writing isn't possible).

Comment: It probably needs to be writable by administrators through the web interface.  If so then this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

A) Use a read-only connection - I think that would be almost the best solution

B) Use more than one TextBox as Input (but this would become more a solution like checking the String for Insert etc.)

For Example

Select |***_*___**| From |**__*_*__*_*___**| Where |**__*_*__*_*_**|

Edit: to answer your comment just have a look at http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html especially the topic "SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY" - I haven't done anything with sqlite now, but I think that should do the trick...